# Evitar que el div inferior se desplace cuando el superior hace scroll vertical

Tags: css, html5

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en angular que no es responsive porque habría que hacer cálculos para redibujar. Mis conocimientos de css son muy limitados, y mi problema es que tengo el div que carga el tree, que hace scroll vertical si se cargan muchos nodos del tree, encima de una barra de controles.
Los width y height de los divs los he calculado en el componente.ts y se cargan en el ngAfterViewInit().
Dejo el código de mi componente.html (los estilos van en el html) y la foto de lo que ocurre.

```
<app-navbar-geochem></app-navbar-geochem>

<div id="parent" style="display: inline-flex" #parent class="pariente">

<div #tree style="overflow: scroll;border:2px solid black">
<div style="width:220px;">

<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" class="tree-node-leaf" #arbol>
  <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index" >
          <input *ngIf="mostrar <= 0"
            (change)="check(node, !node.data.checked)"
            type="checkbox"
            [indeterminate]="node.data.indeterminate"
            [checked]="node.data.checked"
            >

            {{ node.data.name }}
     </ng-template>
   </tree-root>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas #canvas id="canvas" style="overflow-y:scroll;border:2px solid 
   black">
   Tu navegador no soporta canvas.
</canvas>
</div>


</div>

<div class="menu-inferior" #menu style="display: inline-flex;border:2px 
 solid black;margin-top:-8px">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" #recargar2>RECARGAR</button>
    <p><b>LÍMITES</b></p>
    <div  *ngFor="let limiteX of limitesX; let i=index" style="padding-
    left:3px">
      <b>x</b>{{i}}. <input type="text" placeholder="{{  limiteX  }}" 
                      size="1">
  </div>
  <div  *ngFor="let limiteY of limitesY; let i=index" style="padding-
         left:3px">
      <b>y</b>{{i}}. <input type="text" placeholder="{{  limiteY  }}" 
                      size="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Sin scroll]

[image: Con scroll]

*Encontré el problema. Es porque el tree-node está cargado con una librería externa ([libreria tree](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs)), que genera un div por js creo, y es este el que se expande. La solución tal vez aplicar un margin-top dinámico y negativo al contenido inferior.
*No es una solución muy elegante. Para aplicarlo lo único que se me ha ocurrido es crear una funcion setInterval. Funciona bien, con el único inconveniente de que al reagrupar los nodos, durante una fracción de segundo, el texto se cuela hacia arriba, hasta que el setInterval resetea su margin a 0. He tenido que poner la barra arriba y dejar espacio para evitar efectos indeseados.

```
setInterval(
    function() {
      GeochemComponent.tamtree=GeochemComponent.arbolicodeloshuevos[0].clientHeight;
      if (GeochemComponent.tamtree>yWTree) {
        GeochemComponent.debajo.style.marginTop=- (GeochemComponent.tamtree-yWTree)+'px';
      }
      if ((GeochemComponent.tamtree-yWTree)<0) {
        GeochemComponent.debajo.style.marginTop=0+'px';
      }


    },
    10);
```

Comment: Usa el inspector de elementos y trata de seleccionar ese espacio en blanco, trata de seleccionar los elementos cercanos y así podrás mirar que elemento está generando ese espacio

Comment: El que se expande es el div #tree, el que contiene los nodos. No se expande el contenedor padre que contiene al canvas central y la barra derecha también.¿Hay manera de evitar que lo haga?

Comment: Entonces intenta algo, al #tree aplícale un max-height con el valor de la altura que le has dado al contenedor padre. ej: max-height: 500px, prueba con eso

Comment: Disculpa no, pasa algo que no comprendo al ser mi primer proyecto en angular. Se expande algo perteneciente al index.html raíz, que solo contiene un <router-outlet> y una navbar. Si pongo la barra arriba del canvas (que creo que queda mejor en la aplicación), "el hueco" dice que corresponde con la propia barra, que se expande por debajo del canvas(me he quedado flipado, igual tengo algo mal en la forma de plantear el proyecto angular).

Comment: Vale ya está. Es por una clase css del tree, que está cargado usando una librería y genera un div para crear el arbol entero expandido. Gracias.

Comment: Genial me alegra que hayas encontrado la solución

Comment: Bueno, si la encuentro mañana que hoy ha sido un día largo. No lo puedo capar porque corto los nodos que deberían mostrarse. Creo que debo aplicar un padding negativo al contenido inferior, dinámicamente calculado como la diferencia entre ese div que genera la librería y su padre. Lo dejo para mañana a la mañana y edito la pregunta si consigo sacarlo así. salu2

Answer (score 0):

Si usas CSS simplemente incluye en el tag de 'footer'

```
#footer {
    ....
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0px;
   ....
}
```

En tu HTML identifica el DIV como "footer" para que se active ese comportamiento.

```
<div id="footer">Pie de pagina situado abajo</div>
```

Si no quieres modificar ningún CSS simplemente incluye en el DIV tu "*estilo*":

```
<div id="xxx" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px;">Pie de pagina situado abajo</div>
```

Comment: El problema es que debajo quiero incluir contenido, y si dejo el cuadro de la aplicación, o la barra inferior, como fixed, al hacer scroll hacia abajo el usuario en la página el cuadro debería tener un comportamiento static para que no mantenga el cuadro de la aplicación en la vista.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con la propiedad de css position sticky y fixed.

Referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Por ejemplo, con tu menú:

```
<div class="menu-inferior" #menu style="display: inline-flex;border:2px 
 solid black;margin-top:-8px; position:sticky">...</div>
```

ó

```
<div class="menu-inferior" #menu style="display: inline-flex;border:2px 
 solid black;margin-top:-8px; position:fixed">...</div>
```

Comment: Me parece que es una respuesta bastante pobre, esto debería ser más bien un comentario.

Comment: Le he puesto position: fixed al div del menu inferior, pero se sigue desplazando en el scroll.

Comment: Poniéndolo en el div que hace el scroll sí que funciona. ty

Comment: El caso es que aunque no desplaza, crear el bloque fijado me crea algunos problemas adicionales. No me sirve en este caso, creo.

Comment: Si pongo fixed, al tener la pantalla contenido por debajo, distorsiona tras un scroll del usuario. Con sticky se sigue desplazando, al igual que con static, absolute y relative.